# Yii2 Class 'yii\image\drivers\Image_GD' not found

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-extensions

I'm new in the Yii framework. I installed [yurkinx/yii2-image](http://github.com/yurkinx/yii2-image) extension via composer. It worked fine in localhost. But when I moved to ubuntu web server it shows

```
Class 'yii\image\drivers\Image_GD' not found
```

I tried to install `imagemagik` and `php5-gd` but no use.

Comment: Check your include paths :)
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

Comment: Thank you for your earliest reply. I'll check it. :)

Comment: If it didn't help try to add `code` extension=gd.so `code` to Your php.ini file